# how to plot 2 internal tangent circles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

i want to draw 2 circles that are tangent each other from inside, then the smaller one (internal circle) move on another surface. I want to create this function in MATLAB, I mean drawing and moving the circles.

I want to move the smaller circle around another one on the bigger one's surface.

This image shows the positioning of the circles

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky you!

As @Neal Ehardt told, normally you wouldn't find someone that will do this for you, but luckily you found someone who has already codded this in a previous project.

so here is the code:

```
function [circ1,circ2]=tangent_circ(c,r1,r2,phi,n)

alpha=0:2*pi/n:2*pi;
x1=c(1)+r1*cos(alpha);
y1=c(2)+r1*sin(alpha);

paux=[c(1)+r1*cos(phi) c(2)+r1*sin(phi)];
vect=[c(1)-paux(1),c(2)-paux(2)];
vect=vect/norm(vect);
c2=paux+vect*r2;

x2=c2(1)+r2*cos(alpha);
y2=c2(2)+r2*sin(alpha);
circ1=[x1;y1];
circ2=[x2;y2];

end
```

The inputs of this function are

- c: centre of desired circle [x,y] format
- r1,r2 radius of desired circles
- phy: angle of location of inner circle (in radians)
- n num of points

the outputs are 2x(n+1) matrixes of XY coords of the circles.

This code will only output 1 setting of circles. If you want to have something like circular motion you will need to call the function several times for different `phy` values.

**EDIT:** check the code, I made some typos while putting it in a function.
And replaced phy with phi ;)

Comment: i dont understand what is the PHY variable

Comment: @user3525031 the phy variable is an angle. Its the angle in radians of the point where the inner and outer circle touch.

Comment: Pro tip: it's "phi" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find anyone who will code this whole thing for you.  Let me break this problem down into tasks that you can research and solve yourself.

1. Draw a circle on screen.  Google: "matlab draw circle"
2. Animate the circle's position.  Google: "matlab animate position"
3. Create circular motion.  I will help you with the concept here.

For circular motion, you need a variable that represents time (let's call it `t`).  You need functions of `t` that will give `x` and `y` position that progress around a circle.  Sine is your friend here.

```
R = 100 # radius of circular motion
S = 0.1 # speed of animation
x = R * cos(t*S)
y = R * sin(t*S)
```