# How to plot and animate two internal tangent circles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation

I want to draw two circles that tangent each other from the inside, then the smaller one (internal Circle) move on another surface. I want to create this function in [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), I mean drawing and moving the circles:

[image: image2.gif]
<sub>(source: [uga.edu](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMT668.Folders.F97/Anderson/writeup6/image2.gif))</sub>

I want to move the smaller circle around another one on the bigger one surface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to plot 2 internal tangent circles in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391260/how-to-plot-2-internal-tangent-circles-in-matlab)

Comment: @excaza it's my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function M = circles(steps)
    figure
    M(steps) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap', []);
    for i=1:steps
        phi = i*2*pi/steps;
        two_circles(4, 1, phi);
        M(i) = getframe;
    end
end

function two_circles(r1, r2, phi)
    d = r1-r2;
    circle(r1, 0, 0);
    axis square
    hold on
    circle(r2, d*sin(phi), d*cos(phi));
    hold off
end

function circle(r, x0, y0)
    t = 0:.01:2*pi;
    plot(x0+r*sin(t), y0+r*cos(t));
end
```

This code plots two circles and then animates as one of them moves on the surface of the other one.

It also returns an array of frames which could be used in [movie](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) function:

```
M = circles(100);
movie(M, 10, 100);
```

or to create your own [gif image](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab) or video file.

Here is an example of creating gif file from frames array:

```
function frames_to_gif( filename, frames, delay )
    first = true;
    for frame = frames
          im = frame2im(frame);
          [imind, cm] = rgb2ind(im, 256);
          if first
              first = false;
              imwrite(imind, cm, filename, 'gif',
                  'Loopcount', inf,
                  'DelayTime', delay);
          else
              imwrite(imind, cm, filename, 'gif',
                  'WriteMode', 'append',
                  'DelayTime', delay);
          end
    end
end
```

And here is a gif file I created with it:

```
frames_to_gif('circles.gif', M, 1/200);
```

[image: circles.gif]